Is there anywhere I can learn the Yerushalmi cantillation online?
Basically the title, I can’t find anything, maybe y'all know.

My children used Kol Kore (provided by their school) and Yerushalmi is one of the options they have.  https://www.kolkore.com/e/index.php

Torah Box provides a step-by-step online tutoring program for Tunisian cantillation, which is almost identical to the Yerushalmi style.

Can you link directly to the online tutoring program?

Done. You're right, it's much better that way. Please note that it's parsha by parsha, you have to select the parsha you want to practice, then "lecture de la paraha en hebreu" and then of course select Tunisian cantillation.

Unless I'm missing something, this is a recording of the parasha, but doesn't explain how to recreate it, and notes go with what ta'am.

You have the tikkun below with cantillation notes and the recording aliyah by aliyah...that's usually how these things work

I expect a teaching tool to be something like this.
